# How to override a standard link in Salesforce

Tags: page-layout, button-overrides

i have to override a standard link in Home Page layout .My screenshot of Home page layout is

[image: Screen Shot]

i want to open my visualforce page when user click on link on left bottom Approve/Reject link.How to override its functionality please guideline.is this possible or not ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't override that particular link unfortunately. One options is to re-create that list using a Visualforce page, and then put that page into the home layout in place of the approvals section. Querying for existing approvals is quite easy, then you'd just loop over them and provide links to the VF page you want the user to go to.